# conditional include in FSharp

Tags: f#

I would like to convert a bunch of fs files to fsx files.

Each of those fs file reference class defined in, say, base.fs
So instead of being compiled in the project and relying on the compiler resolution, all would be file based.

That means if I have all those file to include base.fsx, and that one file references another, base.fsx would be included twice.

Does anyone know how to make a conditional include with fsx files ?

The [preprocessor documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233195.aspx) states

> There is no #define preprocessor directive in F#. You must use the
>   compiler option or project settings to define the symbols used by the
>    #if directive.

Answer (score 5):

If you're loading all the files from a single `fsx` script, then you can load the individual files from the project in the right order and the individual library files do not need to load `base.fs` directly - the code will be defined, because it has been loaded before.

For example, if you have `base.fs`:

```
module Base   
let test() = 10
```

and you have `more.fs` which does *not* load `base.fs` but uses the functions defined there:

```
module More   
let more () =
  Base.test() + 1
```

then you can load all files in F# interactive (in, say, `script.fsx`) and it will work fine:

```
#load "base.fs"
#load "more.fs"

More.more()
```

The only disadvantage is that you won't get IntelliSense when editting `more.fs` (because the editor does not know about `base.fs`). To workaround that, it is probably a good idea to keep the files in a project in Visual Studio. But you can still load them in F# interactive for experimentation & testing.